# Combining if constexpr() with non const condition

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++17

I'm trying to something like this:

```
if( constexpr( TEMPLATE_BOOL_VALUE ) || bOhterBoolValue )
{
    Foo();
}
else
{
    Baa();
}
```

I usually use a preprocessor macro for such an if statement:

```
#define IF_COND    if( constexpr( TEMPLATE_BOOL_VALUE ) || bOhterBoolValue )

IF_COND
{
    Foo();
}
else
{
    Baa();
}
```

**In Visual Studio 2017, this worked** (I should have but didn't check the generated code, but the compiler accepted this syntax).

**In Visual Studio 2019, now there is an error** "C2760" because it only allows:

```
if constexpr( TEMPLATE_BOOL_VALUE )
{
    Foo();
}
else if( bOhterBoolValue )
{
    Foo();
}
else
{
    Baa();
}
```

Is there another way for doing this without typing two times Foo()?

Hope you can help. I don't wanna get two identical cases.

Comment: Does `if( constrexpr( TEMPLATE_BOOL_VALUE ) || whatever )` actually compile?

Comment: What exactly do you think `if constexpr` achieves?

Comment: "I usually use a preprocessor macro for such an if statement." Please don't.

Comment: @Mike Borkland: There are special cases where I use such macros. In general, I don't. "Usually" only in this context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `Foo();` branch is valid (i.e. compiles) regardless of whether `TEMPLATE_BOOL_VALUE` is true or not, there no need to use `if constexpr`.

Simply use `if (TEMPLATE_BOOL_VALUE || bOhterBoolValue)`.

Comment: Indeed. MSVC will happily remove the branch if it can prove the condition is always false.

Comment: Thanks! That's the solution for my specific problem. But if the const part gets more complex, the compiler maybe generates code. In this simple case you're right. I wonder if there is a general way to combine constexpr() with other values.

Comment: @AntonF. *"compiler maybe generates code"* I would expect modern compilers to be smart enough to not do that. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That is common sense, but sadly not true in all cases. I've some experience in such things. At some depth, optimization stops. Maby VS2019 is better than it's predecessors, but there are always limitations in very complex cases.

Comment: @AntonF. In those cases, assign the value you want to check to a `constexpr` variable beforehand. That way, its value is required to be available at compile-time. If your compiler then still generates run-time code, a bug report to MSVC is probably in order.

Comment: @Max Langhof I will try this.Maybe ther raises a warning, but it could be suppressed.